# Emacs/Aquamacs php-mode and tabs indent

Tags: php, emacs, indentation, aquamacs

I can't get my Aquamacs 2.4 (Emacs) to follow the Kohana style:

Emacs in php-mode replaces tabs with spaces. I want to disable this and use tab-characters for the indention.

I tried many solutions like this, but none works for me:

```
(require 'php-mode)
(setq php-mode-force-pear t)
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
         (setq tab-width 4)
         (setq c-basic-offset 4)))
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
  David

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for tabs for indentation and spaces for alignment then you can use SmartTabs.
(`--->` is a tab, `.` is a space)

```
function example()
{
--->command();

--->if ($condition)
--->{
--->--->$arr = array('One',
--->--->.............'Two'); // Tabs for indent, spaces for alignment.
--->--->other_command();
--->}
}
```

See [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartTabs) and 
[github](https://github.com/jcsalomon/smarttabs) for installation details.